# Why aren't all the area elements used in the calculations?

Tags: python, division

I'm trying to do some simple calculations to get calculated leakage using this formula: `calculatedLeakage=((averageCurrent/(averageVoltage/1000.0))/area[z])`
but I noticed that only the last element of list area is being used in my formula and I can't figure out why (`area` is a list being imported from another file).

```py
for j in range(0,len(mm),1):
    voltageValue=data3[mm[j],i]
    currentValue=data3[mm[j],i+2]
    sumVoltage += voltageValue
    sumCurrent += currentValue
    if (len(mm)!=0):
        averageVoltage = sumVoltage/len(mm)
        averageCurrent = sumCurrent/len(mm)
        for z in range(0,len(area),1):
            calculatedLeakage=((averageCurrent/(averageVoltage/1000.0))/area[z])
            calculatedLeakage=(round(calculatedLeakage,1))
    if (headerFlag==True):
        all.append([header[1:5],header[10:11],header[15:16],calculatedLeakage])
        all2=pd.DataFrame(all)
    else:
        all.append([calculatedLeakage])
        all2=pd.DataFrame(all)
return(all2)
```

The results I get are perfect as far as everything being in the right place but I noticed that my formula only divides using the last element of area.

Comment: Could you please provide a [mcve](/help/mcve)? You might want to read [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask]) too.

Answer (score 0):

Your line `calculatedLeakage=((averageCurrent/(averageVoltage/1000.0))/area[z])` is inside a for loop. Every element of `area` is being used to divide but you are just writing over the results each time.

I think what you might be trying to do is something like this:

```py
if (len(mm)!=0):
    averageVoltage = sumVoltage/len(mm)
    averageCurrent = sumCurrent/len(mm)
    calculatedLeakage=((averageCurrent/(averageVoltage/1000.0))/area[0])
    for z in range(1,len(area),1):
        calculatedLeakage/=area[z]
    calculatedLeakage=(round(calculatedLeakage,1))
```

Comment: Now i only get 0 for my calculated voltage which is it's initialization value.

Comment: @user2241397 are you trying to divide `calculatedLeakage` by every value in area? What is your for loop for? And what do you mean by 'calculated voltage"? That is not in your code.

Comment: I'm sorry, i meant calculatedLeakage. yes exactly, i'm trying to divide calculated leakage by every elements of area and use everything after if (headerFlag==True): to create my data frame for output.

Comment: @user2241397 can you print the result of `calculatedLeakage` after using my code? If the value is 0 after all the division, then maybe you shouldn't round it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the all.append statement also to the first if statement.

```
if (len(mm)!=0):
        averageVoltage = sumVoltage/len(mm)
        averageCurrent = sumCurrent/len(mm)
        for z in range(0,len(area),1):
            # print ("z",z)
            calculatedLeakage=((averageCurrent/(averageVoltage/1000.0))/area[z])
            # print ("area",area[z])
            calculatedLeakage=(round(calculatedLeakage,1))
            all.append(calculatedLeakage)
```

Comment: this works but it returns the whole list of calculated voltage instead of individual values.

Comment: I have a feeling the indentation of you headerflag statement is wrong for what you want to do (if I understood you correctly); try to unindent the last if-else combination and see if you get your expected result.